# How to extract the email from email body using applescript?

Tags: email, applescript, extract

I want to get the email address that i mention in the image.The email i received from my clients and i am using applescripting and 
i want to use that email as recipient.I will send auto mail to this email address.
Thank You.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The concrete solution depends strongly on the HTML text.

You got two options:

- Get the `source` of the message, extract the HTML part, use an HTML parser to get the address or convert the HTML text to plain text with `textutil`.
- Get the `content` of the message – which is plain text – check all paragraphs for email parts and use regex or `sed` or `text item delimiters` to extract the address.